# 'Content-Type' in response headers always 'application/octet-stream'

Tags: node.js, express, get, content-type

I have a simple Node.js Express setup whose purpose is to serve an 'apple-app-site-association' file needed for Apple Universal Links.

My router is setup as follows (rest of the app omitted, standard Express stuff):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

var aasa = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'apple-app-site-association');

router.route('/apple-app-site-association')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pkcs7-mime');
        res.status(200);
        res.sendFile(aasa);
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Now if run this on my local computer, everything is fine, the headers of response I get are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 21:12:32 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 16:22:31 GMT
ETag: W/"c2-3944605092"
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
```

But if I run the exact the same app on my remote server, I get the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 21:13:46 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 16:22:31 GMT
ETag: W/"c2-3944605092"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
```

Somehow the Content-Type I set gets ignored and 'application/octet-stream' is returned.

Any idea what might be causing this? My local computer and the server run the same Node.js (5.3.0) and Express (4.13.3) versions and use exactly the same app. Thanks!

Comment: Is the remote server passing the requests through a reverse proxy? is it messing with the content type header?

Comment: I thought of this as well, because the remote server actually has an nginx instance running that passes some requests to the Express app. But in my tests I have always directly accessed the Express app (I even shut down nginx, just to make sure).

Comment: Have you tried setting the headers via res.sendFile instead? e.g `var options = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pkcs7-mime'
    }
 };

 res.sendFile(aasa, options);`

Comment: Just tried it, still getting 'application/octet-stream' back.

Comment: I'm having the same problem? Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: Actually not. If anyone has ideas how to solve this, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: same i am facing , anybody got solution